# JavaFX - Remove blue line between columns in TableView

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a css dark theme for my javafx app. Everything is ok except one thing: a blue line between the columns in the table view when an item is selected:

[image: screenshot]

And here is what my css file looks like:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-base: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-control-inner-background: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-table-header-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 5;
}

.table-view .column-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .column-header, .table-view .filler {
    -fx-size: 35;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent derive(-fx-base, 80%) transparent;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 10 1 0;
}

.table-view.column-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-border-color: derive(-fx-base, 20%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-base, 20%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `-fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;` into your css. 
Either create a new rule like:

```
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

or just add it into `.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:focused`:

```
.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-border-color: derive(-fx-base, 20%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Result:

[image: result]